# How to use a where statement that does not ignore Nulls in Big Query

Tags: google-bigquery

I was a little surprised to find out that the WHERE statement in Google Big Query ignores NULLS. Does anyone know of a better way to do this?

I have the following data set:

```
Name     Score
Allan     20           
Brian     NULL
Clare     30
```

Say I want to select all records where the Score is not equal to 20. If I use the following code in Big Query

```
SELECT * FROM [....] 

where
    Score <> 20
```

The following is the result:

```
Name  Score
Clare   30
```

The problem is that the record for Brian which is NULL is also not equal to 20 and therefore should be in my results.

Other than checking spefically for NULLS is there a better way to do this?

Thanks
Ria

Comment: Did you tried NOT IN (20) ?

Comment: Operations on `NULL` return `NULL` (which is not `TRUE`). Try it yourself: `SELECT NULL <> 20` will give `NULL`. This is normal, standard behavior for SQL, and all major relational databases do this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

SQL (and thus BigQuery, which is SQL-like), has a trivalent logic. What that boils down to is that statements cannot just be TRUE or FALSE, they can also be NULL. In this case, the statement NULL <> 20 is neither TRUE nor FALSE, it is itself NULL. It might be helpful to think of NULL values as unknown. Since we don't know Brian's age, we don't know whether it is equal to 20. But the query only returns rows for which the where-clause evaluates to TRUE, and therefore the row with Brian is excluded.

If you want to include NULL values, you have to explicitly write

```
where (Score <> 20 or Score is null)
```

Comment: That'll do nicely. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

```
select * from [...]
where coalesce(score, 0) <> 20
```

Comment: `ifnull(score, 0)` makes more sense than `coalesce` to me, since `coalesce` takes the first non null argument, while `ifnull` provides a default value in case the argument is null.

Answer (score 3):

One more variant:

SELECT * FROM [...]
WHERE ifnull(score <> 20, true)

I kind of like it as a way to express "accept either TRUE or NULL boolean values from this expression; reject FALSE."

Answer (score 1):

How you can achieve by-

```
SELECT * FROM [....] 

where
    Score <> 20 or Scrore is NULL
```

Is there any efficient way-

To avoid this performance killing way, we should keep column property as `not null`.